# Relative layout on click listener doesn't take the correct for-loop index

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have created a For-loop that create dinamycally some relative Layouts. I have an arrayList with some elements, called "photosPathList". The size of this arrayList is used to define the max number of loops.
This code that i'm writing is inside the onResume() method of an activity in Android. There is one thing that i'm not understanding.
If i log the i index inside the loop, it is increased correctly, and at each loop it take +1 value.
But if i click on the relative layout listener, the i index has always the last loop position. So if i create 4 relative layouts and i click on the first one, the log inside the relative layout show to me the the number 3. This isn't correctly because it should show the 0 number. Do you agree?
So what i'm doing wrong?

```
for (i=0; i<= photosPathList.size()-1; i++) {

                //RELATIVE LAYOUT
                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this); //create a new relative layout
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, //set main params about the width and height
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grayColor)); //set background color
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                relativeParams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 0);
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams); //set declared params about layout to the relativeLayout
                relativeLayout.requestLayout();
                Log.i("index",""+i);
                   Log.i("current path",""+photosPathList.get(i).toString());
                relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ //create a listener about the layout. When a user press a point inside the relative layout a new activity should be created
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v){
                         Intent photoDetailsActivity = new Intent(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                PhotoDetails.class //assign the class for create a new intent
                            );
                         Log.i("index2",""+i);
                         photoDetailsActivity.putExtra("photoDetailsImagePath", photosPathList.get(i).toString());
                         photoDetailsActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("photosPathList" , photosPathList);
                         photoDetailsActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("formatPhotoList", formatPhotoList);
                         photoDetailsActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("numberCopiesPhotoList", numberCopiesPhotoList);
                         photoDetailsActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("pricePhotoList", pricePhotoList);
                         startActivity(photoDetailsActivity); //let's start the new activity
                     }
                 });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your "i" variable isn't final.

Something you need to understand here:

When your onClick method invokes, it won't know what the value of "i" was during this loop. You need to find a way to pass "i" to the onClicklistener.

My suggestion, create a new class which implements OnClickListener and accepts an int variable.
Save this variable as a class member, and then use that in the OnClick method.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using same variable i for every click event. You should use different counter variables.

Comment: #mysticMagic Yes, but at each loop the i index should have a different value right? So why i need to have a new variable each at loop interaction?

Comment: Check your code properly. Inside list loop, you are using list variable i. So it is behaving this way @Hieicker

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
for (i=0; i<= photosPathList.size(); i++) {

            //RELATIVE LAYOUT
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this); //create a new relative layout
            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, //set main params about the width and height
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grayColor)); //set background color
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            relativeParams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 0);
            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams); //set declared params about layout to the relativeLayout
            relativeLayout.requestLayout();
            relativeLayout.setTag(i);
            relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ //create a listener about the layout. When a user press a point inside the relative layout a new activity should be created
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Intent photoDetailsActivity = new Intent(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            PhotoDetails.class //assign the class for create a new intent
                    );
                    int index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                    Log.i("index2",""+index);
                    photoDetailsActivity.putExtra("photoDetailsImagePath", photosPathList.get(index).toString());
                    photoDetailsActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("photosPathList" , photosPathList);
                    photoDetailsActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("formatPhotoList", formatPhotoList);
                    photoDetailsActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("numberCopiesPhotoList", numberCopiesPhotoList);
                    photoDetailsActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("pricePhotoList", pricePhotoList);
                    startActivity(photoDetailsActivity); //let's start the new activity
                }
            });
        }
```